# How do I set the default theme in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, themes

By default the "theme" option in phpMyAdmin affects the theme only for the browser in which the theme setting is changed (stored in a cookie maybe?).  How do I set a specific theme as the default for all users?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A default theme can be specified from the config.inc.php file in the document root of the phpMyAdmin installation:

```
$cfg['ThemeDefault'] = 'original';
```

source: http://www.wallpaperama.com/forums/_wxxram.html

Comment: In the version 4.6.6 for Linux that file is located in `libraries/config.default.php`